# Convert mongodb query into Spring data mongodb syntax

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to convert this query spring data mongo syntax but facing issue with $add operator.

```
{
        "$project":
            {
              
                "nextYear": {
                    "$dateFromParts":
                        {
                            "year": { "$add": [{ "$year": "$today" }, 1] },
                            "month": { "$dayOfMonth": "$joiningDate" },
                            "day": { "$month": "$joiningDate" }

                        }

                }
            }
    }
```

Tried this without $add it is working, but cant find any documentation regarding $add.

```
 aggregationOperations.add(Aggregation.project()                       
                    .and(DateOperators.DateFromParts.dateFromParts()
                            .year(DateOperators.Year(yearOf("today")))
                            .month(dateOf("joiningDate").dayOfMonth())
                            .day(monthOf("joiningDate"))).as("nextYear"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If pipeline stage looks too difficult or you don't know how to convert it using spring, just try to use this way

```
  import org.bson.Document;
  import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperation;
  ...

  AggregationOperation project = ctx -> Document.parse("""
         { "$project": {
          
            "nextYear": {
                "$dateFromParts":
                    {
                        "year": { "$add": [{ "$year": "$today" }, 1] },
                        "month": { "$dayOfMonth": "$joiningDate" },
                        "day": { "$month": "$joiningDate" }

                    }

            }
        }}
            """);
```

Comment: please share the documentation link from where I can refer to this syntax.

Comment: I found this way manually, actually if you open any implementation of AggregationOperation (e.g. `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.LimitOperation`), you will see that it eventually creates Document that represents a stage in Mongo, so `Document.parse` just converts bson string to the Document.

Comment: I discussed this with my peers, according to them it's a deprecated way of doing this. 
I have to find a correct way of converting this query in spring data

Comment: That's true, but as I can see they may change it to `AggregationOperation#toPipelineStages`, so it shouldn't break existing usage a lot.  Currently `toPipelineStages` just uses `toDocument`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution(not by converting this exact query in spring data).

Used java.util.Calendar to get year value and passed the values to **dateFromParts** year function

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTime(new Date());


 aggregationOperations.add(Aggregation.project()                       
                    .and(DateOperators.DateFromParts.dateFromParts()
                            .year(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1)
                            .month(dateOf("joiningDate").dayOfMonth())
                            .day(monthOf("joiningDate"))).as("nextYear"));
```